# Jenkins Git Refspec not correctly substituted for branch specifier

Tags: git, jenkins, tfs

I am busy integrating Jenkins and TFS. My first unsuccesful attempt was to use Jenkins's multibranch pipeline setup and TFS. So my second attempt is to use a single Jenkins build with a parameter to specify which branch to build.

I've called this parameter `branchRef` and am using it in the "branches to build" field like `${branchRef}`

According to [Team Foundation Server plugin for Jenkins](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin#git-1) I would have to specify the Refspec as follows: `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin-pull/*` This will give me a list of refs like:

```
44553f3184c5cbe04e9838209bc752218cd7e54a refs/remotes/origin-pull/563/merge
8bf10538ee29e9df0745ed4b7b23cb20fe56978d refs/remotes/origin/feature/integration
fa8c14671cb6ce1c3ef6dcca52e9e1f45e914e00 refs/remotes/origin/feature/stable
```

Within TFS I've setup the Build Definition to use a Job parameter like: `branchRef=$(Build.SourceBranch)`. When building a branch and pull-request (merge) I get the following as a parameter:

```
normal branch: refs/heads/integration
pull-request merge: refs/pull/563/merge
```

This gives the following Jenkins behaviour

```
->normal branch
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/integration^{commit}" # timeout=10
->pull-request
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/pull/563/merge^{commit}" # timeout=10
```

So the normal branch Jenkins/Git plugin is translating from `refs/heads/integration` to `refs/remotes/origin/integration` while the pull-request it does not 'translate'.

I've implemented a workaround, which was to change the Refspec to: `+refs/pull/*:refs/pull/* +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` but I don't know if this will or will not cause issues in the long run.

Comment: Have you encountered any issues with your workaround for now? Just 
monitor it, If no issues that should be a good workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested this by trying to duplicate your setup and noticed the same thing:

> So the normal branch Jenkins/Git plugin is translating from
>   refs/heads/integration to refs/remotes/origin/integration while the
>   pull-request it does not 'translate'.

This should not cause any issues in it's current state (unless this confusing behaviour is changed), since the remotes should be fetched each time. As far as I can tell, `refs/heads/integration` becoming `refs/remotes/origin/integration` is irrelevant if you haven't made any local changes on `heads` and `remotes/origin` is fetched.

If you want to be absolutely sure you can compare them using: `git rev-list --count refs/heads/integration..refs/remotes/origin/integration` (it should be 0 if they are the same).

[The difference between `heads` and `remotes/origin`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541040/is-refs-heads-master-same-as-refs-remotes-origin-master-in-git) might be relevant here.

Comment: I have so far not yet encountered issues. But I am also not a great Git guru.

Comment: @DaanTimmer you should not encounter any issues, as I explained in the answer the two should be identical in your case.